# Can anyone tell me in what other way we can diffuse an image without losing specific parts of an image

Tags: image, image-processing

The Perona Malik diffusion equation removes noise from the image on the basis of two points:

- preferring high contrast edges over low contrast ones.
- preferring wide regions over smaller ones

Can anyone tell me in what other way we can diffuse an image without losing specific parts of an image like edges, image content, lines and other details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an anisotropic method that claims to preserve edges while reducing noise. See

http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=541427

Diffusion operators by nature remove features, that's how it removes the noise. So there is always some loss associated. But by choosing to diffuse different near edges (either diffuse less, or diffuse tangent to the edge rather than normal), edges can be preserved.

If there are features that cannot be lost, the diffusion operator cannot be applied across them or you run the risk of losing the feature.

Answer (score 0):

More advanced methods are using the Structure Tensor of the image to smooth around edges without blurring them.

Basically, the Structure Tensor gives you information about the local gradient of the image.
Using this info you can smooth "Flat" areas and sharpen areas which are edges.

The Perona Malik is very old and better approaches are available now.

Have a look here:

https://github.com/RoyiAvital/Fast-Anisotropic-Curvature-Preserving-Smoothing